# Cannot get an instance of MediaSessionManager with getSystemService()

Tags: android, api, session, media, android-mediasession

I've been trying out the new Android Lollipop APIs, especially the new media playback control framework. In the documentation, it says to get an instance of the new MediaSessionManager, I have to call `getSystemService(MEDIA_SESSION_MANAGER)`. However, writing the code in Android Studio gives an error saying the argument can only be one of `List of services like POWER_SERVICE, WINDOW_SERVICE, VIBRATOR_SERVICE etc.`

I think it might be a bug with Android studio but I have no probably using all the other new APIs introduced in Lollipop. I have the final Lollipop SDK installed on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get an instance of MediaSessionManager by calling  `context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE)`

You apparently have a typo: you wrote MEDIA_SESSION_MANAGER instead of MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE.

PS: you didn't copy the Android Studio error message correctly in your question, so I can't see what goes after "saying the argument can only be one of". If you are actually using Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE but still get an error, please edit your original question and quote the error message correctly.